# How to connect by MDS excel add-in using HTTPS?

Tags: excel, iis, https, windows-server, master-data-services

I've switched MDS access from HTTP into HTTPS.

1. Web interface works ok
2. Excel add-in generates an error during a connection attempt

The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
The remote server returned an error: (403)Forbidden. (System)

What should be done to work with excel using HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

The Web Application will continue to work after switching to SSL but the Excel add in will not.  To resolve this you must edit the web.config of the Master Data Services web application.  See below link for full details, I believe you would start at step 10 given context.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/install-windows/secure-a-master-data-manager-web-application?view=sql-server-ver15

In my experience the portion needed to make SSL work is already in the web.config but commented out, you just need to uncomment it out and comment out the section that is for Non SSL.  Note there are two different sections.

This is what my bindings section in the web.config looks like after configuring for SSL.

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mdsWsHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          <!--Non-SSL implementations.-->
          <!-- <security mode="Message"> -->
            <!-- <message clientCredentialType="Windows" /> -->
          <!-- </security> -->
          <!--SSL implementations-->
          <security mode="Transport">
          <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mdsBasicHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          <!-- Non-SSL implementations.-->
          <!-- <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"> -->
            <!-- <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" /> -->
          <!-- </security> -->
          <!-- SSL implementations -->
          <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Tested and works with SQL Server 2022, using the Excel plugin for SQL 2019 (as Microsoft haven't released a 2022 specific plugin yet).